# toggle two divs with timer?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have two Divs

```
<div id="squareone"></div>
<div id="squaretwo"></div>
```

And when the page loads I want each div too ->`$('#squareone').animate({top: '1px'},1000);`
The question is - Is it possible to toggle between these two divs automatically when the page loads maybe with a timer or by using the setInterval function?

So when the page loads `$('#squareone').animate({top: '1px'},1000);`

and then `2 secs` later `$('#squaretwo').animate({top: '1px'},1000);`

and then repeatedly for `20 sec`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: You've already pretty much figured out what you need to do. I'd suggest reading up on setTimeout and setInterval

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#square").toggle(
      function () {
       $('.squareone').animate({top: '1px'},1000);
      },
      function () {
      $('.squaretwo').animate({top: '1px'},1000);
      }
    );
       
    });
This is what i came up with but as @hg3 suggested i m now having a look at setinterval ans setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing an infinite recursive loop:

```
function toggleDivs($this){
    var $that = ($this.attr('id') === 'squareone' ? $('#squaretwo') : $('#squareone'));

    $this.animate({top:1},1000,function(){
        toggleDivs($that);
    });
}
```

Then on page load just call it:

```
$(function(){
    toggleDivs($('#squareone'));
});
```

If you want to stop it after 20 seconds:

```
function toggleDivs($this,count){
    var $that = ($this.attr('id') === 'squareone' ? $('#squaretwo') : $('#squareone'));

    $this.animate({top:1},1000,function(){
        if(count <= 20){
            count++;
            toggleDivs($that,count);
        }
    });
}
```

And just include the starting number in the call:

```
$(function(){
    toggleDivs($('#squareone'),1);
});
```

This is because you are animating for 1 second, obviously the number of cycles would change if you wanted to do it faster or slower (`count <= 40` if you did animation for `500` instead of `1000`, for example).